# Dependency injection: Unable to inject Carbon class in custom-helper class in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I created a `app\lib` folder to keep my custom helper class. I added it to autoload in composer.json and ran `composer dump-autoload`.
 For the test purpose I quickly created a class called `MyHelper` and tried to instantiate it and it did work as expected. The custom helper class was nicely loading.

In my application, I needed to work with dates. So I chose to work dates with the help of Carbon extension. I found that it was already in Laravel vendor folder.
 To make easy, I added an `alias` in `app.php`

`'Carbon'          => 'Carbon\Carbon'`

Below is my **`custom helper class`**. (Code below is working fine)

```
class MyHelper{

public $today;

public function __construct(){
    $this->today = Carbon::now();
}
```

In the above code, I am creating a carbon object by doing `Carbon::now()`. This seems ok and working fine but as far as I know, it is better to do dependency injection rather than instantiating within the construct method. This will make testing more easy.

So I modified above construct method as below:

```
public function __construct(Carbon $carbon){
    $this->today = $carbon->now();
}
```

But, the above code does not work. And the error reporting is telling me that argument of construct method must be instance of Carbon\Carbon.

> Argument 1 passed to Date::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Carbon\Carbon, none given

I also added `use Carbon\Carbon as Carbon` but no joy. I think I am misunderstanding some simple logic of Laravel. May be misunderstanding with dependency injection or IOC that resolves classes.

Enlighten me..

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are having problems in instantiating `MyHelper`. Make sure that you pass a `Carbon` to your constructor. I believe you have something like

```
$myHelper = new MyHelper();
```

However, your constructor expects a `Carbon` parameter. Assuming that `$carbon` is a `Carbon` instance, you could do something like:

```
$myHelper = new MyHelper($carbon);
```

EDIT:
Laravel has an Inversion of control, which is used like this:

```
class FooBar {

    public function __construct(Baz $baz)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
    }

}

$fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
```

(taken from [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc))

The `make` method is needed to be used instead of the pure PHP constructor call. Laravel should call the constructor correctly under the hood.

Comment: Isn't it the whole point of doing dependency injection in Laravel is to avoid manually passing of dependent classes/object. If I am instantiating MyHelper class like you mentioned above by passing Carbon object as an argument, it seems so manual.

Comment: In PHP if you have a function which expects a parameter, then you need to pass that parameter.

Comment: yeah I know, it is required in PHP. But the thing is I am creating my application with Laravel and Laravel offers something called Inversion of Control which I was expecting that it should resolve those classes automatically.

Comment: How do you instantiate the class?

Comment: $myClass = new MyHelper ... I know it will work if i pass parameter like you said. But I am talking about in the context of Laravel. Laravel should have known that it is a dependency injection and automatically resolve it without me passing patameter manually.

Comment: Take a look here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc
Instantiating is made using code like App::make('foo'); which calls the constructor with the needed parameter under the hood. But you are instantiating with the new keyword, which is pure PHP and expects a Carbon parameter, just like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove the alias and try
Not sure if there is any need adding alias since u want to inject

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

    class MyClass{

        protected $today;

        public function __construct(Carbon $carbon){
            $this->today = $carbon->now();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It really does not make any sense. I am aliasing so that I can use the alias during dependency injection.

Comment: Anyway, I gave it a try to your solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: OK. How are you calling MyHelper. Copy this to global.php or routes.php(you can move it later) `App::bind('MyHelper', function($app)
{
 return new App\Lib\MyHelper($app->make('Carbon\Carbon'));
});`